# SQL UNION Optimization

Tags: oracle

I have 4 tables named A1, A2, B1, B2.

To fulfill a requirement, I have two ways to write SQL queries. The first one is:

```
(A1 UNION ALL A2) A JOIN (B1 UNION ALL B2) B ON A.id = B.a_id WHERE ...
```

And the second one is:

```
(A1 JOIN B1 on A1.id = B1.a_id WHERE ...) UNION ALL (A2 JOIN B2 on A2.id = B2.a_id WHERE ... )
```

I tried both approaches and realized they both give the same execution time and query plans in some specific cases. But I'm unsure whether they will always give the same performance or not.

So my question is when the first/second one is better in terms of performance?

In terms of coding, I prefer the first one because I can create two views on `(A1 UNION ALL A2)` as well as `(B1 UNION ALL B2)` and treat them like two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is better:

```
(A1 JOIN B1 on A1.id = B1.a_id WHERE ...) UNION ALL (A2 JOIN B2 on A2.id = B2.a_id WHERE ... )
```

It gives more information to Oracle CBO optimizer about how your tables are related to each other. CBO can calculate potentials plans' costs more precisely. It's all about cardinality, column statistics, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Purely functionally, and without knowing what's in the tables,the first seems better - if data matches in a1 and b2, your 2nd query won't join it.

Comment: My database is designed the way no rows in A1 can match B2, and no rows in A2 can match B1, so I can confirm that two queries will always give the same results.